# What are good places to find upcoming rodeo events in Colorado and Utah?

Tags: usa

I will be travelling with my family in the U.S for the first half of April. We'll be flying to Houston and then visit Colorado, Utah, Arizona and New Mexico by car. We'll spend much of our holiday doing day treks in some of the national parks in those states.

We would also like to visit a rodeo show. I have tried to Google for rodeo events in the states we'll visit, but I haven't really found any.

Are there any sites out there which lists upcoming rodeo shows?

Comment: April and rodeos are a bit out of synch. Fort Worth has a rodeo show throughout the year that might work out.